# Merge tags [coverage.py] and [python-coverage]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

From tag descriptions and the questions, it seems to me that the [coverage.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coverage.py) and [python-coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-coverage) tags are the same on Stack Overflow, so I guess they should be merged.

I'd suggest to use [coverage.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coverage.py): it has more questions (174 vs. 58 at the time of writing), and it is actually the name of the [product](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.4/) (with a capital C).

**Edit**: as suggested by @Raidri, making them synonyms is also a good option.

Comment: Or make them synonyms: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/coverage.py/synonyms

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot suggest one, as I don't have the necessary answer score on either of them. But I like the idea.